# Mocking node module in Redux middleware (Jest)

Tags: mocking, redux, jestjs

I'm having trouble mocking a function from a third-party node module in a Redux app.

I am trying to test a middleware function that intercepts a certain action and calls a function from a third-party npm package. (The module is the aws-iot-device-sdk, and the function establishes a websocket connection to the AWS IoT service)

```
import awsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk'

// ...

const customMW = (store => {

  let websocket = null

  return next => action => {
    switch(action.type) {

      case 'CONNECT':

      websocket = awsIot.device({
        accessKeyId: action.accessKey
        // other params...
      })

      // Listen to events etc.
      break
      // ...
    }
  }
})
```

`awsIot.device()` establishes the websocket connection, and it works fine.

However when I try to test the `customMW` function, `awsIot.device()` is called even though I am attempting to mock it (store and next are appropriately mocked):

```
test.js

describe('middleware test', () => {

  it('does something', () => {

    awsIot.device = jest.fn()
    action = { type: 'CONNECT' }
    customMW(store)(next)(action)
    // assertions...
  })
})
```

When I run the test, I get the error that 'accessKey' is undefined. So the middleware is running the original `awsIot.device()` function which is looking for 'accessKey' to be passed in as part of the action.

I have used this pattern elsewhere with success. Does anyone know why this function is not being mocked?

Answer (score 2):

To mock something that you import in the file you want to test you have to use `jest.mock`. This will overwrite the imported module before it will actually imported. If you want to check that `awsIot.device` was called in you test you have to import the module in you test as well and then use expect like this:

```
import awsIot from 'aws-iot-device-sdk'//only needed if you wanna test that device method was called

jest.mock('aws-iot-device-sdk', ()=>({
  device: jest.fn()
}))

describe('middleware test', () => {

  it('does something', () => {
    action = { type: 'CONNECT' }
    customMW(store)(next)(action)
    expect(awsIot.device).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Comment: I still get the same error. It seems like jest is just completely ignoring my mocked functions.

Comment: Could you log `awsIot` in you component, to check if it was mocked.

Comment: Yes it is... so weird. In fact if I extend your suggestion and add a mock implementation to `.device`, I can see that being correctly returned in my original file. But for some reason the very next line (which calls the exact same function appears to ignore this...)

Comment: Ok for some reason I need to pass in the correct `action` object even though I am mocking the function. It seems to have normal behaviour if I use `action = { type: 'CONNECT', accessKey: 'test' }`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around this by combining Andreas' suggestion with the fact that I had to supply the correct 'shape' action in my test.

```
action = {
  type: 'CONNECT',
  accessKeyId: 'testKey'
}
```

It seems the mocked function will still read arguments passed to it and if there are reference errors there then it will error.